# Webserver to Android JSON parsing data

Tags: android, json, webserver

please have a look at my basic Android-Webserver code.
Data should from Android smartphone should be sent to a webserver, webserver should put data in database and then give the query:
{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}

(when i access the server-side script via browser i get this JSON-message, also the data is insterted into database)

The problem is that my app doesn't parse the JSON response correct or even doesn't get any response?

My code so far:
http://bits.works/view/466210bb

The code shows "Error parsing JSON data" on Android screen.

```
Call of method:

//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

new SignupActivity(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this).execute(Double.toString(latitude), Double.toString(latitude), Double.toString(longitude), Double.toString(longitude), Double.toString(latitude));
```

Class with method:

```
public class SignupActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private Context context;

public SignupActivity(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String fullName = arg0[0];
    String userName = arg0[1];
    String passWord = arg0[2];
    String phoneNumber = arg0[3];
    String emailAddress = arg0[4];

    String link;
    String data;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    String result;

    try {
        data = "?fullname=" + URLEncoder.encode(fullName, "UTF-8");
        data += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
        data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(passWord, "UTF-8");
        data += "&phonenumber=" + URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumber, "UTF-8");
        data += "&emailaddress=" + URLEncoder.encode(emailAddress, "UTF-8");

        link = "http://qqqqqtech/signup.php" + data;
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        result = bufferedReader.readLine();
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    String jsonStr = result;
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");

            if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Check the returned value from `doInBackground` before the line

```
 String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
```

This is because `doInBackground` might have caught an exception and returned that instead of a valid response. So, make a `Toast` with `jsonStr` before trying to parse it to see what it contains.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String jsonStr = result;

        Toast.makeText(context,jsonStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (jsonStr != null) {...

It seems that jsonStr is empty.